# For AWS download functionality, how to also avoid downloading if the file hasn't changed?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, retrofit, etag

### Background

I'm working on a project that uses `com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3` dependency to download files from the server.

```
fun downloadFile(context: Context, bucketName: String, fileName: String, file: File, transferListener: TransferListener) {
    val transferUtility =
        TransferUtility.builder().s3Client(AmazonS3Client(AnonymousAWSCredentials()))
            .context(context.applicationContext).build()!!
    val observer =
        transferUtility.download(bucketName, fileName, file)
    observer.setTransferListener(transferListener)
}
```

### The problem

The app needs to get the new file for time to time (a JSON file in this case, but can be anything else). Currently it checks with Firebase-RemoteConfig on some trigger, and if it's a new value, it downloads the file. I find it weird and unnecessary.

I want to avoid using RemoteConfig for this purpose. It makes it more annoying to manage updating of the files.

### What I've found

If I has Retrofit here, I could have used Etag or something like that for a last-modified-time of the file:

https://medium.com/android-news/reducing-your-networking-footprint-with-okhttp-etags-and-if-modified-since-b598b8dd81a1

I've tried to search about the same thing for AWS, but I couldn't. I found some for uploading, but here it's completely different.

I also couldn't find how to use what's recommended instead of the CTOR of AmazonS3Client, which is deprecated. It says I need to `Use AmazonS3Client#AmazonS3Client(AWSCredentials, com.amazonaws.regions.Region)` , but when what to put for each...

Later I tried to use Retrofit instead:

```
interface FileDownloadService {
    @GET
    @Streaming
     fun downloadFile(@Url fileUrl:String): Call<ResponseBody>
}

@WorkerThread
fun test(context: App, url: String) {
    Log.d("AppLog", "test")
    val cacheSizeBytes = 1024L * 1024L * 2L
    val builder = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
    builder.cache(Cache(context.cacheDir, cacheSizeBytes))
    val client: OkHttpClient = builder.build()
    val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
    retrofitBuilder.baseUrl("https://s3.amazonaws.com").client(client)
    val retrofit = retrofitBuilder.build()
    val service: FileDownloadService = retrofit.create(FileDownloadService::class.java)
    val response = service.downloadFile(url).execute()
    Log.d("AppLog", "isSuccessful?${response.isSuccessful} ${response.code()} ${response.raw().code} ${response.headers()["Last-Modified"]}")
}
```

This has multiple issues:

1. On emulator, it keeps getting response code 200 (instead of `HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED`) and takes a long time (4 seconds). I could just use the header "Last_Modifed" as this seems to be fetched well, though.
2. On device, I keep getting `UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "s3.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname` .
3. The app already uses Retrofit in other places. I don't know if this could cause more issues as it probably uses different configuration, different threads, ...

### The questions

1. How can I detect when the file has changed, avoiding downloading of the file?
2. What should I use instead of the CTOR of AmazonS3Client that I see here?
3. Is is possible to use Retrofit as I've shown? If so, what's wrong with how I did it?

Comment: Not sure who "I" is for the first question, your mobile app or your system, and if mobile app how often does the app need to be notified (polling or notification). For the 3rd question, I'm not sure if you've read: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-bucket-intro.html as your aws S3 bucket site name doesn't appear correct (but could have been placeholder).

Comment: @MorrisonChang About "I", I mean the myself, in the Android app that I need to change its code. It's currently already polling using RemoteConfig. I want to avoid this and use the URL directly. The code works fine for the AWS code. I just changed the URL to what's already possible to reach via a web browser. What should I change for the code of Retrofit to make it work?